# Why are there only two query types in the Go Database library?

Tags: go

From what I can tell, there are only two types of results the Go `database/sql` interface library expects back - [a row](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) or an [array of rows](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query). However, there is at least one more type of result - a single column.

```
DB.column('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE `banned` IS NOT NULL')
```

Is there any way to handle this - or do I just have to fetch a row and then access the `COUNT(*)` from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you fetch a one column row but is that so hard ?

```
var count int
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE `banned` IS NOT NULL")
err := row.Scan(&count)
```

Note that this may be compacted if you find it too verbose (you may remove the row variable).

I think that other similar systems in other languages (for example JDBC) don't offer natively this shortcut either.

I find easier to handle an API that I can memorize and browse rather than an API which has all the utilities I might be willing to use to remove one line in my code.

Comment: Yes, it's not an big problem. However, concise code is on of the touted benefits of Go. Therefore, since it's only one additional method I was just wondering why it was missing since it logically seems like this method should exist instead of having to work around it. Single column SQL results are fairly common.

Comment: The reason is probably the will to have a simple and minimal API. Note that it's easy to make a function returning an int and an error from a query.

Comment: There are only three result types at database can return though: a value, an object, or an array of objects. Leaving one off because it makes things simpler is like leaving integers out because we can use floats for them.

Comment: @Xeoncross  SQL databases typically makes no internal distinctions between a result set of 1 column and 1 row (i.e. a single value) , and a result set of 10 columns and 1 row, or 1 column and 10 rows etc. There's one common type of result you forgot though, which is returning multiple result sets, a feature commonly provided by SQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, a SQL Server stored procedure returns all of the following (at the same time):

- an integer return code
- zero or more messages (often warnings or errors) containing text and two integer codes
- zero or more named, typed scalar output parameters
- zero or more "rowsets", each of which is an ordered list of zero or more rows.

Within a rowset, all rows have the same number (one or more) of named, typed columns.  The column names do not have to be distinct within a rowset.

SQL Server does not recognize any special cases, like a single rowset with a single row or a single column; or a single output parameter.

Other database systems are slightly different.